# A4Tech Bloody V7 мышка - не работают боковые кнопки в терминальной сессии

Tags: консоль, rdp, мышь

Мышка A4Tech Bloody V7

Боковые кнопки настроены на Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V

На основном компе все работает замечательно. Без сбоев и стабильно.

Но, когда я пользуюсь этими же кнопками в терминальной сессии, то они срабатывают через раз.

Т.е. работают, запоминают в буфер, вставляют нормально, и вдруг, ни с того ни с сего, вместо копирования в буфер вставляется тупо символ "с" на место выделенного текста.

Или, если пытаешься вставить, то, вместо текста в буфере обмена, вдруг вставляется "v". Если несколько раз повторить, то опа, вставляется нужный текст.

Такое впечатление, что до терминалки не всегда долетает виртуальное нажатие клавиши Ctrl, которое должно отсылаться при нажатии боковой кнопки мыши.

Я заметил, что чаще всего это происходит после переключения в терминалке из одного окна в другое.

Очень хочется, чтобы нажатие на эти боковые кнопки работали стабильно, как нажатие на клаве - в буфер, из буфера...

А так приходится постоянно затирать эти символы с и v и вставлять или копировать заново...

Процент ошибочных срабатываний примерно 10%. Но жутко раздражает необходимость возвращаться и исправлять неверное срабатывание клавиш

Comment: Интересно.. почему мой вопрос минусуют?
И куда делись комментарии к этому вопросу? 
Почему их удалили?

Comment: А как же `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`C` и `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`V`?

Comment: @v1nc3nt_0'ne1ll  Ctrl+Shift+C и Ctrl+Shift+V используются для других функций.
Копирование в буфер и вставка делаются клавишами  Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V. Эти комбинации клавиш настроены на две боковые кнопки мыши - для ускорения работы и удобства использования. Кнопки используются постоянно. Но _иногда_ не срабатывают так как нужно.... : (